# Typescript type guard function for typed array building

Tags: typescript

Consider following code:

```
interface A { a: number }
interface B { b: string }

function isA(a: any): a is A  {
  return a.a !== undefined;
}

function isB(b: any): b is B  {
  return b.b !== undefined
}

let a1: A = {a: 1}
let a2: A = {a: 2}
let b1: B = {b: 'A'}
let b2: B = {b: 'B'}



let mixed: (A | B)[] = [
  a1, a2, b1, b2
]

/* Naah, error */
let filteredA: A[] = mixed.filter((e) => {
  return isA(e)
})

/* Naah, error */
let filteredB: B[] = mixed.filter((e) => {
  return isB(e)
})
```

Assignation to `filteredA` and `filteredB` is still not possible, as type `A|B is not assignable to A` (or `B` accordingly).

As per my understanding, type guarding and it's type narrowing shall do exactly the trick. Is my understanding wrong?

Is there any other, elegant way to filter union type array per types?

Comment: You've created anonymous arrow functions without return types, throwing away the type predicate - they just return boolean instead. You can see this if you make the generic type of `filter` explicit with e.g. `mixed.filter<A>(...)`: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgILIN7LgLmSAVwFsAjaZAXwChRJZEUAhTZEvAZzClAHNKqqMAiARhgAexDJg7VAApc2EAE8AlHjjT2aZJiq6oEMAShS4AOk0BCALw3kwgCYQYoCI4DcValQA2R5CJgAA93PDl0AB9kRlUAbQBdZHtEgQB6ACpkADk4OAALABpkaChxKGQMtL8A1186d1Q8VETkwJD3czq6AB5UAD45OQhVZP69AyMTKRl5Ee9VKiA.

Comment: I posted an answer then realized "Wait, I think the only reason I know this is that I've seen it here on SO" and sure enough, found an earlier version of much the same question. But having done the answer, I wanted to share it with you: https://tsplay.dev/mMRndW

Comment: @T.J.Crowder marvelous, thank you!